# Haml print at same line

Tags: haml

I want to print HAML at same line

```
  %ul
    - @categories.each do |c|
      %li= c.name 
      (#{c.posts.count})
```

and I recive

```
<ul>
  <li>vim</li>
  (3)
  <li>bash</li>
  (1)
</ul>
```

How to get

```
<ul>
  <li>vim(3)<li>
  <li>bash(1)</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
%li= "#{c.name} (#{c.posts.count})"
```