# Print additional information on an erb line with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I have this:

```
<h1 class="left"><%= pluralize @player_to_team_histories_count.count, "Player" %> Found
```

(notice the addition on of the word "Found")

How do I do that in haml?

```
%h1.left= pluralize(@player_to_team_histories_count.count, "Player") Found
```

complains about `Found` not being a defined constant

Comment: Probably related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591796/haml-print-at-same-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, ask and you'll figure it out:

```
%h1.left= "#{pluralize(@player_to_team_histories_count.count, 'Player')} Found"
```

Comment: In this case just `%h1.left #{pluralize(@player_to_team_histories_count.count, 'Player')} Found` is probably simpler (no `=` and no quotes).